# HttpWebResponse how does it end

Tags: c#-4.0

n pages that there is no content length, how does HttpWebResponse
knows where the page ends? And what kind of objects/methods does it
retrieve? Does it only retrieve the initial page without any images,
i.e., does it only makes one "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"?

```
In other words, does HttpWebResponse only gets the specified html page
without any objects? When there is no Content-Length property, how does
it know when the page ends?
```

Answer (score 0):

Client knows that page ended when server closes the connection. Learn more about HTTP [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).
HttpWebResponse retrieves page source code, like you would retreive it with `TcpClient`.